# How to convert a Series to a Dataframe and pivot it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series which looks like below

```
col1  A
col2  B
col3  C
```

I would like to convert it to a dataframe which looks like

```
col1, col2, col3
 A,     B,    C
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `s.to_frame().T
`

Answer (score 1):

```
series.to_frame().T
```

[This](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) is for converting series to dataframe.